# playa template tags being ignored

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

EE 2.7.2
Playa 4.4.5

I have two playa fields in my Recipes channel field group.

One is called similar_recipes, which relates to other entries within the recipes (which happens to be the channel this form is posting to).

The other is related_products.

```
{similar_recipes}
    {if count > 0}<h3>Similar Recipes</h3>{/if}
    <p>
        {recipe_image}
            <a href="/recipes/view/{url_title}" title="{title}"><img src="{image:url:small}" alt="{title}"></a>
        {/recipe_image}

        <a href="/recipes/view/{url_title}" title="{title}">{title}</a>
    </p>
{/similar_recipes}


{related_products}
    {if count > 0}<h3>Related Products</h3>{/if}
    <p>
        {product_image}
            <a href="/products/view/{url_title}" title="{title}"><img src="{image:url:small}" alt="{title}"></a>
        {/product_image}

        <a href="/products/view/{url_title}" title="{title}">{title}</a></p>
{/related_products}
```

[image]

I tried using the dynamic parameter, thinking it may be an issue with the fact I have a playa field that relates to its own entries, but I don't think thats the issue.

As you can see in the attached image, it acts like those fields do not exist in the channel field group.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a variable name conflict. You can use "var_prefix" when this happens. Try something like this:

```
{exp:playa:children channel="recipe" entry_id="{entry_id}" field="similar_recipes" var_prefix="related" }
    {related:title}
{/exp:playa:children}
```

http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/children.html

Comment: Added entry_id="{entry_id}" to exp:playa:children ... and it worked perfectly, thanks again.

Comment: You're most welcome... I added entry_id="{entry_id}" to me example code.